# Java - HttpUrlConnection contains HTTP document instead of JSON

Tags: java, json, youtube, httprequest

I am trying to download a MP3 file of a given youtube file from Youtubeinmp3.com

Sometimes its work pretty good and sometimes the api returns an HTTP document instead of a JSON object. I tried to send different requests to the API with the help of a foreach loop and getAudioLink function, as you can see in the code below.
My musicTitle Object contains three strings (the VideoID, VideoTitle and ThumbnailURL). All of them are stored in a list which is created every time I start a search.

But i dont know why the API sometimes returns a HTTP document instead of a JSON object. The error code I get is triggered from parsing the HTTP document and can also seen below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ....

    for (MusicTitle musicTitle : myList) 
    {
        System.out.println(getAudioLink(YOUTUBE_URL_C + musicTitle.getVideoID()));
    }
}

public static String getAudioLink(String inputLink) 
{
    String result = null;
    HttpURLConnection request = null;
    URL url = null;

    try 
    {
        url = new URL("http://YoutubeInMP3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=" + inputLink);
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader((InputStream)request.getContent());

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser(); // GSON-Library


        JsonObject youtubeInMP3 = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();

        if (youtubeInMP3 != null) 
        {
            result = youtubeInMP3.get("link").getAsString();
        }
        request.disconnect();
        reader.close();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Error Code:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $
at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
at Main.getAudioLink(Main.java:51)
at Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1573)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1423)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:546)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
... 2 more
```

**EDIT 1**

For example if i search for the band "Volbeat" it returns the HTTP document seen below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Your MP3 Is Ready</title>
<meta name="description" content="Download and alternatively edit your YouTube video before saving the MP3 on your device." />
<meta name="keywords" content="edit, download, convert, youtube, mp3" />
<meta name="author" content="YouTube In MP3" />
<meta name="distribution" content="global">
<meta name="language" content="en" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?v=1.2.2">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic|Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body class="home">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<header>
<p><a href="/"><img src="/images/icon.png" class="verticalAlign" alt="YouTube In MP3 Icon"> <span class="logoText">YouTubeInMP3.com</span></a></p>
<nav>
    <ul>
                    <li><a><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x verticalAlign"></i> Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="/tos/">Terms of Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/api/"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x verticalAlign"></i> API</a></li>
        <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x verticalAlign"></i> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
</nav>
</header>   
    <div id="contain-160" class="ad ad-160 loader"></div>

<div class="link-popup" id="linkpopup">

    <div class="popup">

        <h2>Link to this MP3</h2>

        <p><i class="fa fa-link fa-2x verticalAlign"></i> Direct Link:</p>
        <code>http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2Y4t9elm_A</code>


        <p><i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x verticalAlign"></i> Forum:</p>
        <code>[url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2Y4t9elm_A]Download MP3 - Volbeat - Mary Ann's Place (Official Video)[/url]</code>


        <p><i class="fa fa-code fa-2x verticalAlign"></i> HTML:</p>
        <code>&lt;a href="http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2Y4t9elm_A"&gt;Download MP3 - Volbeat - Mary Ann's Place (Official Video)&lt;/a&gt;</code>

        <a onclick="toggle_visibility('linkpopup');" class="close">&times;</a>

</div>

</div>

<div class="link-popup" id="editShow">

    <div class="popup">

        <div class="paddingBottomOptions">

             <h2><i class="fa fa-scissors"></i> Cut MP3</h2>

            <input placeholder="Cut From" class="cutMP3Slider" type="text" id="slider-margin-value-min" /> - 
            <input placeholder="Cut To" class="cutMP3Slider" type="text" id="slider-margin-value-max" /><br />

        </div>

        <div class="paddingBottomOptions">

             <h2><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show video editor</h2>
            <div class="checkBoxDiv">

                Display Video Editor: <input class="checkBoxRight" type="checkbox" id="displayEditor"><br />
                Always display Video Editor: <input class="checkBoxRight" type="checkbox" id="permanentDisplay">

            </div>

         </div>

        <div class="paddingBottomOptions">

            <h2><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> ID3 Tags</h2>
            <div class="checkBoxDiv">

                Identify ID3 Tags Automatically: <input checked="checked" disabled class="checkBoxRight" type="checkbox" id="autoID3">

            </div>

        </div>

        <h2><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Change MP3 name</h2>
        <input class="fullWidth" value="Volbeat - Mary Ann's Place (Official Video).mp3" placeholder="MP3 Name" type="text" id="customMP3Name" />

         <a onclick="toggle_visibility('editShow');" class="close">&times;</a>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="link-popup" id="shareShow">

     <div class="popup">

        <h2>Spread the word</h2>

        <div class="socialButtons">

            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/YouTubeInMP3com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Simple way to extract audio and download MP3s from YouTube:&url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com&description=Simple way to extract audio and download MP3s from YouTube&media=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/images/icon.png"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-3x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tumblr.com/share?v=3&u=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com&s=Simple way to extract audio and download MP3s from YouTube"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square fa-3x verticalAlign"></i></a> 


        </div>

        <h2>Facebook</h2>

         <div class="facebookMargin">

            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

            <div class="fb-page" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/YouTubeInMP3com" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="http://www.facebook.com/YouTubeInMP3com"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/YouTubeInMP3com">YouTubeInMP3.com - Download MP3 Files From Youtube</a></blockquote></div></div>

         </div>

        <a onclick="toggle_visibility('shareShow');" class="close">&times;</a>

     </div>

</div>

<section class="video">

     <form id="form" action="" method="GET">

        <input id="video" type="search" name="video" placeholder="Paste A Link Or Search For A Video Title" />

        <!-- Small screen search results -->
        <div id="searchResultMobile" class="searchResultMobile loader"></div>

        <button id="searchButton" onclick="search()" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Convert To MP3</button>

        <!-- Large screen search results -->
        <div id="searchResultLarge" class="searchResultLarge loader"></div>

    </form>

            <link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.0.2/nouislider.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.0.2/nouislider.js"></script>

     <div class="embed loader">

         <div id="player"></div>
         <div id="slider"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="infoBox">   
        <h1 class="titleVideo"><img class="thumbnailTitle" alt="YouTube Thumbnail" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/-2Y4t9elm_A/default.jpg"> Volbeat - Mary Ann's Place (Official Video)</h1>
                    <p class="floatLeft"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Length: <span class="bold">
| 
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/YouTubeInMP3com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Simple way to extract audio and download MP3s from YouTube:&amp;url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com&amp;description=Simple way to extract audio and download MP3s from YouTube&media=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/images/icon.png"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-2x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x verticalAlign"></i></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tumblr.com/share?v=3&u=http://www.youtubeinmp3.com&amp;s=Simple way to extract audio and download MP3s from YouTube"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square fa-2x verticalAlign"></i></a> 

            <script src="/js/social.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        </p>    

                    <div id="status">

        </div>

        <p class="download-buttons fullWidth">

                            <a class="button fullWidth" id="download" href="get/?i=6%2FARY3w4SlqKhP7hMpnw8skpb2vhQEwDg9rFg6URKpAEbyz736HFUpKqz6uO8TSy5YETAnmYwF995a0lNbbZLw%3D%3D"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Convert &amp; Download MP3</a>
                            <a onclick="toggle_visibility('editShow');" class="button button-gray"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Settings</a><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtubeinmp4.com/youtube.php?video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2Y4t9elm_A" class="button button-gray"><i class="fa fa-television"></i> Download in MP4 format</a><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.saveitoffline.com/go/?l=http://www.saveitoffline.com/#http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2Y4t9elm_A" class="button button-gray"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Other Formats</a>
                        </p>


        <div id="contain-300" class="ad ad-300 loader"></div>

        <div class="floatRight">

            <div class="firstBlock">

                <h2 class="firstBlockHeader">How do I download my MP3?</h2>

                Your video has been prepared and is ready to be downloaded.<br />
                To continue, simply press <strong>"Convert &amp; Download MP3"</strong>.<br /><br />

                Your MP3 has been converted to the highest quality possible and ID3 tags have been automatically identified and added.<br />
                You can customize your download by changing the <a class="green" onclick="toggle_visibility('editShow');">Options</a>.<br />

            </div>

            <div class="secondBlock">

                <h2 class="secondBlockHeader">How do I edit my MP3?</h2>

                You can edit your MP3 by clicking "Settings" (grey button, found above on the left side) button.<br>
                There are two ways of editing an MP3 before downloading it:<br>
                <br>
                1) Specify the start and end time manually, in the Settings menu.<br>
                2) Enable the video editor from the Settings menu and use the sliders to set the start and end time.            
            </div>

        </div>          


    </div>

    <span class="messagePage" id="message"></span>

    <link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/client.js?v=1.2.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init" onload="externalLoad()"></script>       
</section>


    <div id="contain-728" class="ad ad-728 loader"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var durationSeconds = 184;
    var videoId = "-2Y4t9elm_A";
    var editMin = '';
    var editMax = '';
    var convert = 1;
</script>
<script src="/js/process.js?v=1.2.1" type="text/javascript"></script>



<footer>
    <p>Want to forbid downloading a file? <a href="/privacy/">Contact us</a>.<br>
    By downloading content from this site, you agree with the <a href="/tos/">Terms of Service</a>.</p>
</footer>



<div class="loader" id="load-160">

    <!-- Conversant Media 120x600 and 160x600 SkyScraper CODE for YouTubeInMP3 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">var vclk_options = {sid:80572,media_id:3,media_type:7,version:"1.4"};</script><script class="vclk_pub_code" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.fastclick.net/js/adcodes/pubcode.min.js?sid=80572&media_id=3&media_type=7&version=1.4&exc=1"></script><noscript><a href="http://media.fastclick.net/w/click.here?sid=80572&m=3&c=1" target="_blank"><img src="http://media.fastclick.net/w/get.media?sid=80572&m=3&tp=7&d=s&c=1&vcm_acv=1.4" width="160" height="600" border="1"></a></noscript>
    <!-- Conversant Media 120x600 and 160x600 SkyScraper CODE for YouTubeInMP3 -->

</div>

<div class="loader" id="load-300">

    <!-- ValueClick Media 300x250 Medium Rectangle CODE for YouTubeInMP3 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">var vclk_options = {sid:80572,media_id:6,media_type:8,version:"1.4"};</script><script class="vclk_pub_code" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.fastclick.net/js/adcodes/pubcode.min.js?sid=80572&media_id=6&media_type=8&version=1.4&exc=1"></script><noscript><a href="http://media.fastclick.net/w/click.here?sid=80572&m=6&c=1" target="_blank"><img src="http://media.fastclick.net/w/get.media?sid=80572&m=6&tp=8&d=s&c=1&vcm_acv=1.4" width="300" height="250" border="1"></a></noscript>
    <!-- ValueClick Media 300x250 Medium Rectangle CODE for YouTubeInMP3 -->

</div>  

<div class="loader" id="load-728">

    <!-- Conversant Media 468x60 and 728x90 Banner CODE for YouTubeInMP3 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">var vclk_options = {sid:80572,media_id:1,media_type:5,version:"1.4"};</script><script class="vclk_pub_code" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.fastclick.net/js/adcodes/pubcode.min.js?sid=80572&media_id=1&media_type=5&version=1.4&exc=1"></script><noscript><a href="http://media.fastclick.net/w/click.here?sid=80572&m=1&c=1" target="_blank"><img src="http://media.fastclick.net/w/get.media?sid=80572&m=1&tp=5&d=s&c=1&vcm_acv=1.4" width="728" height="90" border="1"></a></noscript>
    <!-- Conversant Media 468x60 and 728x90 Banner CODE for YouTubeInMP3 -->

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/loader.js?v=1.2.2"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.onclicktop.com/a/display.php?r=439235"></script>




<!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=8077308; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="6b707000"; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"></div></noscript>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

If I search for popular tracks or bands I receive ~12 of 15 valid results. But if I search for tracks who no one would listen to I receive ~1 of 15 valid results.

Is it possible that the webserver who manage the informations of the YoutubeInMp3 API answers with HTTP documents if it (the webserver) doesnt know the track and the corresponding download link?

**EDIT 3**

As I supposed the problem is, that the webserver doesnt know the track. If I visit the link of the received HTML document manually, I need to confirm that the track is converted. After it I can download it manually and with the help of my program.

So i guess that the HTML response is a clue that the webserver has no valid answer to my request.

Comment: simply, because the response is not Json Object. read out their api if there is any, so problem is not your json

Comment: As i already said, i know that the error is occurred from responsing a HTTP document. But i want to know why i dont get a JSON object. The API documentation is really insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... i dont know why the API sometimes returns a HTTP document

The HTTP document is most likely an error report of some kind.  If that is the case, it (the HTML document) should give you some clues as to what the real problem is.

Print it out the HTML.  If you can't figure out what the report means, add it to your Question so that we can help you.

Comment: Thx for your reply, I added the HTML to my Question